# How to use AWS Dynamodb to store session-like data?

Tags: session, amazon-dynamodb

I saved the sample data structure listed below to dynamoDB.

```
{
 id: 'uuid',
 data: 'data',
 lastModifiedTime: 'Fri Feb 26 2016 16:22:29 GMT+0800 (CST)'
}
```

Is it possible to make the data destroyed itself if the lastModifiedTime showed 24 hours ago?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TTL setting and define the column containing the timestamp (epoch) after which the item is no longer needed. So you will have to add 24 hours to the last modified property in order to expire it after that amount of time.

For more detailed information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html

Answer (score 0):

No, dynamodb is not support this behaviour.

you should:

1. use Redis to store session data
2. if you are still need to use dynamodb, you can create tables to store monthly or weekly data, You can remove old items by simply deleting the tables.
3. write a script to delete this items (less recommended in this case)

update:
dynamodb ttl can support it.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html

Comment: Just use TTL to support autodelete

Comment: @VictorPoloDeGyvesMontero i will update my answer (i answered it before dynamodb ttl was introduced)